# Exclude empty results for HABTM relationship in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-model

Most of the CakePHP documentation seems to tell you how to filter based on a concrete relationship result. What I cannot seem to find is how to filter out results which have a relationship that returns no data.

For example, take the typical blog example which has Posts and Tags. Tags has and belongs to many Posts (HABTM). For this discussion, assume the following table structure:

```
posts ( id, title )
tags ( id, name )
posts_tags ( post_id, tag_id )
```

How do you find only the Tags which have one or more Posts associated with them (i.e. exclude Tags which would return no Posts)?

The ideal result set would look something like (quotes added for formatting):

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [Tag] => Array (
                      [id] => 1
                      [name] => 'Tag1' )
            [Post] => Array (
                      [0] => Array (
                              [id] => 1
                              [title] => 'Post1' )
                      [1] => Array (
                              [id] => 4
                              [title] => 'Post4' ) )
    )
    [1] => Array (
            [Tag] => Array (
                      [id] => 4
                      [name] => 'Tag5' )
            [Post] => Array (
                      [0] => Array (
                              [id] => 4
                              [title] => 'Post4' )
                      [1] => Array (
                              [id] => 5
                              [title] => 'Post5' )
                      [2] => Array (
                              [id] => 6
                              [title] => 'Post6' ) )
    ) )
```

Comment: [this post](http://www.volved.com/index.php/2009/03/26/cakephp-12-group-by-with-having-count-habtm-associations-limit-the-query-based-on-associated-data/) seems to address this issue; but for 1.3.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've ever found to do this in a reliable way is to use [ad hoc joins](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/nate/2009/01/21/quick-tip-doing-ad-hoc-joins-in-model-find). Using these, you can specify an inner join type and get exactly what you want.

Comment: Maybe I missed something, but after trying out the syntax in the link, I get an array where yes the Tags do have Posts, but the Tag appears multiple times (once for each associated Post). Also, the Post title does not link in. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The following was tested with Cake 1.3.

To start you probably want to, or already do, have the HABTM relationship defined on the models for all the other circumstances where this normally applies:

```
class Post extends AppModel {
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = 'Tag';
}

class Tag extends AppModel {
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = 'Post';
}
```

According to Cake's own documentation:[[1](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1039/Associations-Linking-Models-Together#Joining-tables-1047)]

> *In CakePHP some associations (belongsTo and hasOne) perform automatic joins to retrieve data, so you can issue queries to retrieve models
>   based on data in the related one.*
>
> *But this is not the case with hasMany and hasAndBelongsToMany associations. Here is
>   where forcing joins comes to the rescue. You only have to define the necessary joins
>   to combine tables and get the desired results for your query.*

Excluding empty HABTM results is one of these times. This same section of the Cake Book explains how to accomplish this, but I didn't find it overly obvious from reading the text that the result achieves this. In the example in the Cake Book, they use the\ join path Book -> BooksTag -> Tags, instead of our Tag -> PostsTag -> Posts. For our example, we'd set it up as follows from in the TagController:

```
$options['joins'] = array(
    array(
        'table'      => 'posts_tags',
        'alias'      => 'PostsTag',
        'type'       => 'INNER',
        'foreignKey' => false,
        'conditions' => 'PostsTag.tag_id = Tag.id'
    ),
    array(
        'table'      => 'posts',
        'alias'      => 'Post',
        'type'       => 'INNER',
        'foreignKey' => false,
        'conditions' => 'Post.id = PostsTag.post_id'
    )
);

$tagsWithPosts = $this->Tag->find('all', $options);
```

Make sure to set the foreignKey to false. This tells Cake that it should not attempt to figure out the join condition and instead use only the condition we supplied.

It's common that this will bring back duplicate rows due to the nature of the joins. To reduce the SQL returned use a DISTINCT on the fields as necessary. If you want all fields as is normally returned by find('all'), this adds the complication that you need to hard code each column. (Sure your table structure shouldn't change that often, but it could happen, or if you may just have a lot of columns). To grab all columns programmatically, add the following before the find method call:

```
$options['fields'] = array('DISTINCT Tag.'
                   . implode(', Tag.', array_keys($this->Tag->_schema)));
// **See note
```

It is important to note that the HABTM relationship runs *AFTER* the main select. Essentially, Cake gets the list of eligible Tags and then runs another round of SELECT statement(s) to get the associated Posts; you can see this from the SQL dump. The 'joins' we manually setup apply to the first select giving us the desired set of Tags. Then the built-in HABTM will run again to give us ALL associated Posts to those tags. We won't have any tags which have no Posts, our goal, but we may get posts associated with the tag that are not part of any of our initial 'conditions', if they were added.

For example, adding the following condition:

```
$options['conditions'] = 'Post.id = 1';
```

Will yield the following result:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [Tag] => Array (
                      [id] => 1
                      [name] => 'Tag1' )
            [Post] => Array (
                      [0] => Array (
                              [id] => 1
                              [title] => 'Post1' )
                      [1] => Array (
                              [id] => 4
                              [title] => 'Post4' ) )
    )
)
```

Based on the sample data in the question, only Tag1 was associated with our 'conditions' statement. So this was the only result returned by the 'joins'. However, since the HABTM ran after this, it grabbed all Posts (Post1 and Post4) that were associated with Tag1.

This method of using explicit joins to get the desired initial data set is also discussed in [Quick Tip - Doing Ad-hoc Joins in Model::find()](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/nate/2009/01/21/quick-tip-doing-ad-hoc-joins-in-model-find). This article also shows how to generalize the technique and add it to the AppModel extending find().

If we really only wanted to see Post1 as well, we would need to add a 'contain'[[2](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable)] option clause:

```
$this->Tag->Behaviors->attach('Containable');
$options['contain'] = 'Post.id = 1';
```

Giving the result:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [Tag] => Array (
                      [id] => 1
                      [name] => 'Tag1' )
            [Post] => Array (
                      [0] => Array (
                              [id] => 1
                              [title] => 'Post1' ) )
    )
)
```

Instead of using Containable you could use bindModel to redefine the HABTM relationship with this instance of find(). In the bindModel you would add the desired Post condition:

```
$this->Tag->bindModel(array(
    'hasAndBelongsToMany' => array(
        'Post' => array('conditions' => 'Post.id = 1'))
    )
);
```

I feel that for beginners trying to wrap their head around the automagic abilities of cake, making the explicit joins is easier to see and understand (I know it was for me). Another valid and arguably more 'Cake' way to do this would be to use unbindModel and bindModel exclusively. Teknoid over at http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com has a good write up on how to do this: http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/07/17/forcing-an-sql-join-in-cakephp/. Additionally, teknoid made this into a Behavior which you can grab from github: http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2009/09/26/habtamable-behavior/

** This will pull the columns in the order defined in the database. So if the primary key is not defined first it may not apply DISTINCT as expected. You may need to modify this to use array_diff_key to filter out the primary key from $this->Model->primaryKey.